# Click android hardware back button in tab ActivityGroup

Tags: android

Please anybody help me how to handle the back button in the tab activity group.

My app chin is :

Login - > synchronization  -> main scrren .This main Activity contain 3 tab. Each tab contain more than 5 activities.Thats why I created the ActivityGroup.

Now the problem is When I click the back button from tab's activity (anywhere in tab activity) , It goes to "synchronization  " screen. I want to go previous screen

That mean

MainActivity contain 3 tab called "Sale , Admin ,"Setting" .Take first tab

Sales -> Route ->Retailer -> Retailer Option ->Invoice ... like there are some intent is available.

For example Now I the position "Retailer Option" I click back button , then I should go to  "Retailer " activity

But curently working my code like its went to "synchronization  " .It didn't go to "Retailer " screen.

Please help me this ....

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this

pls try this...

```
  @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) 
    {
        if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```